# JQuery selector matching .data() array dynamically

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have a list of events that users can filter by choosing a series of check boxes.  I've attached data to each event using (I've hard-coded the true/false values to simplify):

```
$(thisDiv).data({
    "Category": {
        "Category1": true,
        "Category2": false,
        "Category3": true,
        "Category4": true,
        "Category5": false
    },
    "Topic": {
        "Topic1" : true,
        "Topic2" : false,
        "Topic3" : false,
        "Topic4" : true,
        "Topic5" : true
    }
});
```

When users select/deselect corresponding checkboxes I want to hide/show events based on the corresponding value, e.g if the Category1 checkbox is selected I want to select all of the events where Category1 == true. (Think like an Amazon book search where you want to filter books by an author or a genre.)

My problem is the syntax I'm using to select matches:

```
$(checkboxes).change(function() { 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var group = this.groupName; //an attribute I added to the checkbox that contains the key (e.g. "Category" or "Topic")
        var identifier = this.id; //e.g. "Category1"    
        $(eventContainer).each(function() {
            //alert($(this).data(group).identifier);  //.data(group) alone returns object, but once I add .identifier it fails
       if ($(this).data("Category").Category1  == true) { //works
           //show/hide events based on other conditions
       };        
        }); //end function
    }
}); //end function
```

What is the correct syntax to select items that match the criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
$(this).data(group)[identifier]
```